# curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: 15.04, curl

I'm trying to install a framework using `curl` but I keep getting this annoying error message `curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`. Does any one know how to fix this? I'm stack!

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy curl libcurl3`

Comment: did you use official `cURL` or the one manually compiled? By default `cURL` https support is enabled in official release.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue after some hours of trying various options! Here's what I did:

Downloaded from http://curl.haxx.se/download.html.

```
tar -xzf curl-***.tar.gz
cd curl-*.*.*
./configure --with-ssl
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: You will also need to install `open-ssl` before you do the above commands. Otherwise ssl is still disabled. `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Answer (score 1):

Officially cURL does not support HTTPS. The answer above didn't work for me, already tried download new versions added with --with-ssl command and got no lucky, this answer solved my problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28782797/8146700

- Content link -

> I still don't know why using Aptitude installs a version without support for HTTPS but building from scratch did the trick:
>
> git clone https://github.com/bagder/curl.git
>   sudo apt-get build-dep curl
>   cd curl
>   ./buildconf
>   ./configure
>   make
>   sudo make install
>
> Now curl -V yields
>
> Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets

Comment: It is generally better to include the main steps you followed in your answer here, with a link to the answer that worked for you - just in case the link goes dead.