# A mystic curl error on Ubuntu

Tags: curl

I do have a mystic error:

```
CMake Error : downloading '' failed

    status_code: 1
    status_string: "Unsupported protocol"
    log: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

  Closing connection -1
```

upgrading said I had the newest version of curl, and a recently installed cmake 3.2. What else shall I check?
(reinstalling curls as suggested in http://devendraverma.com/install-curl-on-ubuntu-14-04/ did not help.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl](http://askubuntu.com/questions/683857/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl)