# Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: curl

When I try `curl http://google.com` it works however when I do it with https, it gives this error:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I've searched for various answers but none explains how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add the following command and results to your question: `curl --version | grep Protocols` .... Helpful as well if you could give the exact curl command that is failing?

Comment: The output of `which curl` and `apt-cache policy curl` would provide some helpful insight too.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/683857/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl

Comment: Did you set proxy? Try to unset http_proxy or https_proxy if it was set.

Comment: How is this the right answer. I tried to install myself and got countless errors. --with-ssl says that SSL is not available.  Why isn't what you get from apt install curl going to be the right thing?  It was on other ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 12):

Please install `curl` with SSL

Download:

- [curl Releases and Downloads](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Installing with SSL:

- Unzip -> open terminal inside the directory PATH and type:

  ```
  ./configure --with-ssl
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

*You can also specify the path to SSL installation, see `./configure --help` for details*

Comment: i have curl already bro, its not working with ssl only,

Comment: @nabtron: Benny suggests you download, compile and install curl with SSL support.

Comment: You need `libssl-dev` installed if you want SSL support. `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Comment: thank you!  That was the missing link.

Answer (score 5):

A quick google found [this curl FAQ](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#configure_doesn_t_find_OpenSSL_e) on troubleshooting this problem.

But I actually would suggest to delete your current manual install of curl, and just install it with `sudo apt-get install curl`. The default Ubuntu install has the right libraries for https (and many more).

Comment: I did it as `curl <site> --insecure`