# curl: (1) Protocol "'smtps" not supported or disabled in libcurl - I've tried the common solutions

Tags: 16.04, curl

Having issues connecting to a SMTP server with curl. The script I am running has worked on other hosts so its an issue with curl. Ubuntu version 16.04 (xenial). The  pre installed curl version was 7.47. Everytime I run a command similar to this `curl --url \'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465\' ...the rest of the args` I get the error

> curl: (1) Protocol "'smtps" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Very strange since I've had previous ubuntu installations that came with curl pre installed and had smtp support.

```
curl --version
```

outputs this

> curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
>   Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
>   Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets

as you can see smtp and smtps are listed as protocols but i am unsure whether they are the ones enabled or supported?

Heres what I've done following the advice of similar threads

uninstalled curl with `sudo apt-get remove curl` then followed the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683857/curl-1-protocol-https-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl)

whenever it was time to run the configure script i gave it the following options

`./configure --with-ssl --enable-smtp --enable-smtps`

after i finished, i got the same error... Then i tried reinstalling with apt-get install curl. but still get the same error. What gives? if there are no ways to resolve this gracefully, could I accomplish the same thing with wget?

Comment: I just tested your start with my account and I got the same error with the `\'` on the smtps part.  If I removed those it worked fine.  Leaving the `'` or no quotes there didn't matter and it worked fine either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a leading apostrophe (`'`) since you're escaping it with a backslash (`\`) - The output is a bit hard to read but `curl` is trying to tell you this, but since it's next to some double quotes (`"`) it doesn't stand out:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "'smtps" not supported or disabled in libcurl
--------------------^
```

Comment: holy cow you are 100% correct, I was copying and pasting the test command and I didnt realize the `'` was still in there. Everything worked and I just threw away a few hours of my life haha. Thanks for pointing that out.